# firstElementChild in Firefox works but Webkit returns null

Tags: javascript

I have a div with `contenteditable="true"` and a string in the text set to strong. After selecting `mytext` Firefox returns `firstelement` correctly as strong but in Webkit it returns `null`. Why is that?

```js
function test() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.type == 'Range') {
            const selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            const clone = selRange.cloneContents();
            const firstelement = clone.firstElementChild;
            console.log(firstelement);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="texteditor" contenteditable="true">
    This is a <strong>test</strong>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Can you make a working demo as a snippet in your question?

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet that can be run inside your question (which is what I meant by "a working demo") - I am using Chrome (webkit) and it seems to return `null` when nothing is selected or when text outside of the `<strong>` is selected. When I select any part of the `<strong>` it returns `<strong>t</strong>` for example

Comment: @ChrisBarr Exactly. FF works fine but webkit returns null when only the bold text is selected but strong if you select it with one character before or after. I can use modify() to extend the selection in the script and then it would work (a simple RTE). Would look better if I do that but also extend it one character backwards. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into the properties and I found `selRange.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode` which seems to work in Chrome when you select just the "es" from "test".

You can probably use it to see if the parent node is the node you expect or not

Will that get you what you need?

```js
function test() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.type == 'Range') {
            const selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            const clone = selRange.cloneContents();
            const firstelement = clone.firstElementChild;
            console.log(selRange.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="texteditor" contenteditable="true">
    This is a <strong>test</strong>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Perfect. I can use this with webkit and the other with Firefox. Thank you.